# moving average on different size data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, moving-average

I have a set of data taken every 5 minutes consisting of the following structure:

```
>df1 

Date                  X1
01/01/2017 0:00       1
01/01/2017 0:30       32
01/01/2017 1:00       65
01/01/2017 1:30       14
01/01/2017 2:00       25
01/01/2017 2:30       14
01/01/2017 3:00       85
01/01/2017 3:30       74
01/01/2017 4:00       74
01/01/2017 4:30       52
01/01/2017 5:00       25
01/01/2017 5:30       74
01/01/2017 6:00       45
01/01/2017 6:30       52
01/01/2017 7:00       21
01/01/2017 7:30       41
01/01/2017 8:00       74
01/01/2017 8:30       11
01/01/2017 9:00       2
01/01/2017 9:30       52
```

Another vector is given consisting of only dates, but with a different time frequency:

```
>V1

Date2
1/1/2017 1:30:00
1/1/2017 3:30:00
1/1/2017 5:30:00
1/1/2017 9:30:00
```

I would like to calculate the moving average of `X1` but at the end the only values I really need are the ones associated with the dates in `V1` (but preserving the smoothing generated by the moving average)

Would you recommend to calculate the moving average of `X1`, then associate the value to the corresponding date in `V1` and re-apply a moving average? or do you know a function in R that would help me achieve this?

Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Sofía

Comment: How many days/hours/mins of Moving-average are you looking forward to apply?

Comment: Well, actually I have a very big data set, this was just a fraction of it, so it doesn't really matter how many elements we use in this example. I've seen your answer below, do you think calculating the moving average of df1 and the simply associating each value with the corresponding date and time on V1 would be a good approach? would it keep the smoothing of the moving average?

Comment: It depends on your need. My answer considers moving average of `4` rows (means 2 hours). You can try different `periods` (width of `rollapply`) like 4 hours, 8 hours etc in order to get desired result. Have a look at help for `rollapply`.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is a convenient way to construct moving averages

Assuming you want a simple arithmetic moving average, you'll need to decide how many elements you'd like to average together, and if you'd like a one or two-sided average.  Arbitrarily, I'll pick 5 and one-sided.

```
elements <- 5
df1$x1.smooth <- filter(df1$X1, filter = rep(1/elements, elements), sides=1)
```

Note that "moving.average" will have `elements-1` fewer elements than `df1$X1` due to the moving average being undefined until there are `elements` items to average.

`df1` is now

```
              Date X1 x1.smooth
1  01/01/2017 0:00  1        NA
2  01/01/2017 0:30 32        NA
3  01/01/2017 1:00 65        NA
4  01/01/2017 1:30 14        NA
5  01/01/2017 2:00 25      27.4
6  01/01/2017 2:30 14      30.0
7  01/01/2017 3:00 85      40.6
8  01/01/2017 3:30 74      42.4
9  01/01/2017 4:00 74      54.4
10 01/01/2017 4:30 52      59.8
11 01/01/2017 5:00 25      62.0
12 01/01/2017 5:30 74      59.8
13 01/01/2017 6:00 45      54.0
14 01/01/2017 6:30 52      49.6
15 01/01/2017 7:00 21      43.4
16 01/01/2017 7:30 41      46.6
17 01/01/2017 8:00 74      46.6
18 01/01/2017 8:30 11      39.8
19 01/01/2017 9:00  2      29.8
20 01/01/2017 9:30 52      36.0
```

Now you need only `merge` the two data frames on `Date = Date2` or else subset `df1` where `Date` is `%in%` `V1$Date2`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. do you think calculating the moving average of df1 and the simply associating each value with the corresponding date and time on V1 would be a good approach? would it keep the smoothing of the moving average?

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use `zoo` package. One can use `rollapply` to calculate and add another column in dataframe that will hold moving average for `X1`.

A implementation with moving average of width `4` (every 2 hours) can be implemented as:

```
Library(zoo)
#Add another column with mean value
df$mean <- rollapply(df$X1, 4, mean, align = "right", fill = NA) 

df
   #                   Date X1  mean
   # 1  2017-01-01 00:00:00  1    NA
   # 2  2017-01-01 00:30:00 32    NA
   # 3  2017-01-01 01:00:00 65    NA
   # 4  2017-01-01 01:30:00 14 28.00
   # 5  2017-01-01 02:00:00 25 34.00
   # 6  2017-01-01 02:30:00 14 29.50
   # 7  2017-01-01 03:00:00 85 34.50
   # 8  2017-01-01 03:30:00 74 49.50
   # 9  2017-01-01 04:00:00 74 61.75
   # 10 2017-01-01 04:30:00 52 71.25
   # 11 2017-01-01 05:00:00 25 56.25
   # 12 2017-01-01 05:30:00 74 56.25
   # 13 2017-01-01 06:00:00 45 49.00
   # 14 2017-01-01 06:30:00 52 49.00
   # 15 2017-01-01 07:00:00 21 48.00
   # 16 2017-01-01 07:30:00 41 39.75
   # 17 2017-01-01 08:00:00 74 47.00
   # 18 2017-01-01 08:30:00 11 36.75
   # 19 2017-01-01 09:00:00  2 32.00
   # 20 2017-01-01 09:30:00 52 34.75
```